# Understanding about locus

Tags: definition, locus

As I have been studying about locus,then I came across its definition as
Locus is a set of points which satisfies a given condition or property (law/equation/rule)

We have been taught about some locus which are as follows

1. Straight line
2. Circle
3. Parabola
4. Hyperbola
5. Ellipse

My question is -

- Square
- Rectangle
- Trapezium
- Rhombus
- Triangle

Whether these all are locus? If no,then explain in a detailed way.

Comment: A locus is a place; a place that satisfies conditions. For example, a rectangle with diagonal $(a.b)-(c,d)$ is a locus whose conditions are $a\leq x \leq c$ and $b\leq y \leq d$

Comment: Consider some set $S$, one in the above list. Consider the property $P$ of a point to be in $S$. Then the locus of the points satisfying the property $P$ is the set $S$. To have a less trivial case, draw two lines in the plane. Which is the locus of the points that have distance $\le a$ from each of the lines? (Well, it will be a "compact, full, set, not only a "boundary", but the idea of what kind of properties determine which shapes should be clear...)